# How to access IMAP server through a proxy server

Tags: python, proxy, socks

i am trying to get all inbox emails from an emails in yahoo, cause of many emails in a day ,yahoo refuse my connections for a while , i want to connect via proxy when yahoo refuses my actual ip and gives that erro :

```
Cannot connect to : Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate).
```

is there a way to connect to yahoo IMAP over proxy ?
i tried this way but no luck :

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4,proxy_ip,port,True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.mail.yahoo.com")
a = M.login(user, passwd)
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to really debug the problem. Your script doesn't contain an example that can reproduce the problem (since I don't know what `proxy_ip_port` or `port` is), and it doesn't provide a meaningful error description (ie. the behaviour you're getting).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker proxy_ip and port are variables , you can have one in a free proxy list , yahoo refused my connection and gaves me  "Cannot connect to : Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)." error .

Comment: Are you sure you're authenticating correctly (good username/password, right auth method)? Does it work when you remove the proxy, or do you get the same error?

Comment: yes i am sure , cuz i use the same script to do that , idon't change it , it work some times ,and gives that error after several connections.if i run this script from other server it gives the results normal. thanks for answering :)

Comment: this code didn't work at all , my original script doesn't contain the proxy. i just want to do it with a proxy so i can connect as much as i want .

Comment: this code is working , the problem was the proxy it self , i wasn't testing with compatible server ,i guess .

Comment: This is why you should provide a *complete* example to demonstrate the problem :-) I didn't even try to reproduce it, since I knew that it would take me quite some time to set it all up, and there might be a good chance that I wouldn't be able to reproduce it. Anyway, I'm glad you fixed the problem ;-)